# Me.dirty or Me.Recordset.EditMode

Tags: ms-access, vba

Which option is the best to know if the screen data have been modified or not. I have the form linked to an ADO recordset. For example I could use `Me.dirty` or `Me.Recordset.EditMode`. Which one would you choose? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think is better `me.recordset.editmode` (more accurate I think)

So I am not using the me.dirty flag to do any testings (Instead using `recordset.editmode`) but I think is better to put the correct value to this flag after modifying a record by setting `me.dirty` to `true` or `false`